# How to see progress of query execution during handle?

Tags: delphi, events, dataset, progress

I used the following code in delphi for handle :

```
procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1FetchProgress(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; Progress,

  MaxProgress: Integer; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);

begin

    Progressbar1.Visible:=true;

    Progressbar1.Max:=MaxProgress;

    Progressbar1.Ppsitian:=Progress;

    Progressbar1.Visible:=false;

end;
```

but....
I can't see any effect (this code doesn't execute)

I want to show progress of query execution during when the user clicked a button for ٍُSEARCH in database from begining to finish filter in progressbar.

the button onclick codes :

```
with ADOQuery1 do

begin

SQL.Clear;

SQL.Add('select * from tbl1 where id = '+Edit1.Text);

Open;

end;
```

but i don't any mutation in the progress bar , as though don't write any code in  OnFetchProgress event.

Did i represented you?

Comment: Please add more information. We can't help from this. Do you mean your procedure isn't getting called? In which case, it's nothing to do with the procedure itself but the code that's arranging for it to be called, but you've not shown us any of that.

Comment: Are you retrieving your records [asynchronously](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/adofetchingrecordsasynchronously_xml.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must set property [`ExecuteOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.ExecuteOptions) to [`eoAsyncFetch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fetching_Records_Asynchronously) before to call the open procedure

check this sample

```
with ADOQuery1 do
begin
 SQL.Clear;
 SQL.Add('select * from tbl1 where id = '+Edit1.Text);
 ExecuteOptions:=[eoAsyncFetch];
 Open;
end;


procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1FetchProgress(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; Progress,
  MaxProgress: Integer; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Max      :=MaxProgress;
  ProgressBar1.Position :=Progress;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```