# How to fetch record count from ADO Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-2009

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see progress of query execution during handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237112/how-to-see-progress-of-query-execution-during-handle)

I would like to show a progress bar indicating how much time it would take to fetch the results from database.

I use `TADOQuery` and open it in Async mode.  While the query state is `stFetching`, is there any way to know the [number of records fetched / total records]?

Comment: @RBA, it is duplicate, that's right, but the code there shouldn't use `Application.ProcessMessages` and it is based on the same mistake as I thought before Sertac edited my post here.

Answer (score 4):

Write a handler for the [`OnFetchProgress`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.OnFetchProgress) event. From the reference:

> Write an OnFetchProgress event handler to take specific action during
>   an asynchronous data retrieval operation. The OnFetchProgress event
>   fires periodically during the data retrieval to provide indications of
>   its progress. Create a handler for this event to react to this
>   periodic notification, such as providing the user with a visual
>   indication of the progress of the data retrieval.

Note that the `MaxProgress` value that will be passed to the `OnFetchProgress` event is a *best guess*. From [How To Use the ADO FetchProgress and FetchComplete Events](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262311):

> MaxProgress is not equal to the actual number of records that will be
>   returned. ADO has to fetch the records in order to get this value.
>   This means MaxProgress is only ever a best guess. MaxProgress usually
>   equals Progress plus Background Fetch Size.

You can issue a `Select Count() ..` to the database as mentioned in Diego's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971055/243614) before you open your query to get an exact total number of records that will be retrieved, but that's not always desirable as it might lead to redundant table scan and considerable execute time for complex queries.

Comment: I missed to check the docs! Thanks :-)

Comment: Will this help with the total record count?

Comment: @Sertac, in docs is written, *MaxProgress is the total number of records to be retrieved by the operation.* so it depends on what is the *operation*. But if that `MaxProgress` indicates the overall number of records to be retrieved or just a number of records for a single batch I can't tell nor verify at this time.

Comment: @TLama - *".. MaxProgress is only ever a best guess. MaxProgress usually equals Progress plus Background Fetch Size.*" ([MS support article link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262311))

Comment: @Sertac, so if I get it right, for a progress bar implementation you need to get max value of a progress with a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WhatYouWantToFetch`, then fetch those data with something like `SELECT * FROM WhatYouWantToFetch` and in the `OnFetchProgress` event set the progress bar's position to the value of `Progress` parameter passed to the event handler ?

Comment: @TLama - Yes, and a 'COUNT' can be quite expensive depending on the query.

Comment: @Sertac, yes, but also the only way to have a real fetch progress bar as it seems... Could you post your suggestions as the answer, please ?

Comment: @Pavan, could you unaccept this answer, please ? It's basically wrong as Sertac pointed out...

Comment: @Sertac, thanks! But I was thinking about your own post :-)

Answer (score 1):

dont think you can predict the future :)

Before the load, submit a count to the DB to know how many records will be loaded.

Build the load on batches and on each batch, compare the size of the batch * amount of batcheswith the total number of records.