# Loading Icon while processing logic in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am getting some data from database and displaying to user using Grid. As data size is very large it will take few seconds to load data to grid. I trying to show Loading cursor symbol while process of loading data is going on.

LockGrid(); // This will disable the controls so user can not make any event.

// Want to dispaly loading symbol here.

Start updating data

UnlockGrid(); // release the controls

Any ideas to accomplish this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't

```
Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
try
  // Do the job
finally
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

do the job?

However, you might also want to consider putting the work in a separate thread. After all, if you don't, your UI will become unresponsive during the entire job.

Depending on the type of grid, you might also be able to call `BeginUpdate` before and `EndUpdate` after the loading of the data. That might speed up the process significantly.

Comment: What is `BeginUpdate`, `EndUpdate` ? I thought that you usually call method pair `DisableControls`, `EnableControls` on the linked dataset.

Comment: @TLama: I'm thinking of `TStringList.BeginUpdate`, of course. However, I know nothing about database functionality, so there might well be better solutions in such a setting.

Comment: @Andreas, ah, I see. I was thinking about data aware DB grid.

Comment: Actually, `TDBGrid` will populate visible rows only and fetch remaining data on demand (showing `crSQLWait` in process)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use an OnProgress callback to either animate an icon, or increment a progressbar, like in this question:
[How to see progress of query execution during handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237112/how-to-see-progress-of-query-execution-during-handle/4239136#4239136)